# Regular expression to match all alphabets, whitespace and a colon

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression which matches contains all words then a space and followed by a colon

```
  [All alphabets][whitespace][colon]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following pattern can be use in Ruby, Perl, JavaScript, .Net...
`[a-zA-Z]+\s+:`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this:

```
[a-zA-Z]+[\W];
```

This works matches like so:

`test ;` `test2 ;` this doesnt work however this `does ;` `work ;`